# How to simulate mouse movement on android phone?

Tags: java, android, mouse

Hi Mighty People of Android Devices, I wanna play CounterStrike CS 1.6 on my phone. (The thing is called X-ash-3D engine and CS 1.6 client and these use the common CS files installed on my PC). Beside its touchscreen controls it accepts common PC mouse and keyboard either USB OTG or bluetooth connected. But i wanna control it (the turning and look up-down part) with orientation sensor from another android device. Here is my Android rotation on PC installed CounterStrike

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PeTkpkx2USY

It uses HyperIMUI to stream sensor data through WIFI to my PC and i wrote a small Java program to translate orientation sensor data to mouse movements with "robot(x,y)".

The question is there any solution for Android that makes the "robot(x,y)", aka sends spoofed mouse movement on system level what is used then by all apps running.
With PC it works (see youtube link above).

It would be more simple if i dont have to use a second device just the one where i play with CS. (if i can stream/access sensor data through Local host like on PC 127.0.0.1 )
Thankx Guys

Comment: This is not possible, except perhaps on rooted devices or with a custom firmware build.

Comment: is it possible in rooted device?